# SQL using count function to find commonality

Tags: sql, count

I'm having trouble creating a query that will display the info I need in the way I need to be displayed. This driving me crazy because its querying only one table and seems like it should be simple. Figuring how to use the count function in this case is frustrating.

I need to find the facids of any faculty who teach classes in a room which has other faculty members who also teach a class in that room. But I cannot include any rooms where only one faculty member uses the room. My result must have three columns: the facids for both faculty and the room on one line. Also, the result cannot repeat the same pair of facids on different lines.

The relevant table CLASS looks like this:

```
CLASS
-----
*classid
facid
sched
room
```

Here is the actual CLASS table:

### # CLASS #

### ## CLASS ID, FACID, SCHED, ROOM ##

```
ART103, F101, MWF, H221
CSC201, F105, MWF, M110
CSC203, F105, MWF, M110
HST205, F202, MWF, H221
MTH101, F110, MWF, H225
MTH103, F110, TTH, H225
```

This is what the query return should look like (I just cant figure the sql out to get there)

### FACID, FACID, ROOM

F101, F202, H221

This is what I have tried so far which has returned the info that I need, just not in the correct format (three columns, no repeating facids in the rows)

```
SELECT facid, room, 
  FROM class
  GROUP BY class.facid, class.room
  HAVING Count(classid)<2;
```

Hope you season pros can help this rookie out! Thank you.

Comment: So far, I used: SELECT facid, room FROM class GROUP BY class.facid, class.room HAVING Count(classid)<2; BUT this doesn't result in three columns. I need the facid's of the faculty that teach in the same room on one line. Another way of saying this is the column should look like this: Column 1: facid (facid of 1st teacher that uses the room) column 2: facid (facid of other teacher that uses same room) Column 3: room (room that is shared by teachers not teaching the same class)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you maybe edit your question and add the table definitions, and the SQLs you tried?

Comment: just added an edit, hope that makes the problem more clear. Thanks again everybody!

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and an example result set?

Comment: Is it really important not to show multiple rooms (rows) for a pair of teachers if they match on more than one room? -- OR -- Do you really need to see the room number, if you're going to arbitrarily show only one room per pair of faculty.

Comment: I need to see the room and facids of both teachers. That is, the rooms that are assigned to more than one faculty member that do not teach the same class in the room.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT facid, room, COUNT(*)
FROM Class
GROUP BY facid, room
```

Comment: Hmm It seems like what I've tried is querying the right info, but isn't in the formatting I need with the three columns and no repeating facid in the rows.

Comment: Hmmm... Can you give an example of some rows in the table and the result of the SELECT statement you need?

Comment: I don't think you understood the complexity of what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I added the table in the edit and the results I need. I hope that helps to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first part of the problem, find the rooms that are shared, then list the faculty who use that room.

```
 with r as
 ( select room, count(distinct facid) as teachers
     from class
     group by room
     having count(distinct facid)>1
 )
 select distinct c.facid, c.room
   from class c
   join       r  on c.room = r.room
```

Then you are asking to pair two faculty members onto a row together, if they share the room together.  We will match them together only with the left facid being less than the right facid, so that we don't get the same pair reversed.

```
 with r as
 ( select room, count(distinct facid) as teachers
     from class
     group by room
     having count(distinct facid)>1
 ), t as
 ( select distinct c.facid, c.room
     from class c
     join       r  on c.room = r.room
 )
 select a.facid as fac1, b.facid as fac2, a.room
   from t as a
   join t as b   on a.room = b.room
                and a.facid < b.facid
   order by fac1, fac2
```

So you have two faculty members and the room.  This is closer...

But wait, now you want to only show one room if the teachers both share several of the same rooms together.  So now we have a bit of a theoretical problem in such a situation.  How would you pick which of those rooms to show?  It would be simpler not to show the room at all, or to have a row for each of the rooms they share.  (My suggestion is the latter.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `COUNT` function. Just join the table onto itself to get the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT  t1.facid
        , t2.facid
        , t1.room
FROM    class AS t1
        INNER JOIN class AS t2
            ON  t1.room = t2.room
            AND t1.sched = t2.sched
WHERE   t1.facid != t2.facid
```

Results:

```
facid   facid   room
F101    F202    H221
F202    F101    H221
```